# Spring REST secure DELETE only the owned (the one created by app end-user, ONLY) resource

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I try to find the best solution in how safety (by the owner only) DELETE a REST resource.

**GOAL:
The resource could be deleted only by the owner/creator of that resource (means the one it created that resource).**

**Premises:**

1. Each time an application end-user creates a client account he receives back a JWT token.
2. To be able to access a REST resource the client should provide a valid JWT.
3. The validation of the JWT is done for each incoming calls through a customer filter:

   @Component public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

   ```
       @Autowired
       private ClientAuthService clientAuthService;

       @Autowired
       private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

       @Override
       protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

           final String authorizationHeaderDate = request.getHeader("Date");

           if (authorizationHeaderDate != null){

               if (DateTimeUtil.isLaterInMinThenNow(
                       LocalDateTime.parse(authorizationHeaderDate,
                               DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), 2)) {

                   final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

                   String username = null;
                   String jwt = null;

                   if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                       jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                       username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
                   }

                   if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                       UserDetails userDetails = this.clientAuthService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                       if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                           UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                                   = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                           usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                                   .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }

   }
   ```
4. The current implementation of the DELETE REST end-point is:

   ```
   @DeleteMapping("/clients/{id}")
   public ResponseEntity<Client> deleteClientById(@PathVariable(required = true) Long id){
       return ResponseEntity.ok(clientService.deleteClientById(id));
   }
   ```

Letting like each end-user having a valid JWT could delete another end-user client account.

**For a hacker is easy to get a JWT, intuit a client ID and delete, one-by-one, all clients accounts**

**The question is: How can I prevent such a security issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use Spring's expression based access control:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

You can annotate your REST endpoint method or service method and use EL expressions to authorize your user. Here's an example from Spring's documentation that you can adapt:

```
@PreAuthorize("#n == authentication.name")
Contact findContactByName(@Param("n") String name);
```

Now - you didn't ask, but you should consider conforming to the REST convention of using the HTTP verb that matches what your action does (i.e. use DELETE HTTP actions for requests that delete resources):

Do not a REST service that uses GET HTTP methods to delete resources - to anyone that knows anything about REST this is not going to make sense:

`@GetMapping("/clients/{id}")`

It should be

`@DeleteMapping("/clients/{id}")`

Comment: Regarding using HTTP DELETE verb you are perfectly right and for someone reading this topic. I recommend to translate "you should consider"  with it is "mandatory" (even the spring, REST theory, do not impose such strict limitation) using those verbs. My mistake was just a stupid copy/paste I've done which I've yet corrected.

Regardnig the issue instead, I'll investigate and eventually complete this topic with an example. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually the situation is like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018509/strange-architecture-to-secure-the-restfull-services-spring-boot-authenticati
I'll try and see if is working, too